# NASM coprocessor - calculating square equation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, equation

Below is shown the code that calculate a solution of square equation (meanwhile we calculate a delta). As a result we get two values: delta and final solution.
I have some problem with element of delta for current values: instead got 3 `(49-4x10=9, sqrt(9)=3)`, I got 9. Considering that we've got 9 instead 3, as a final result we receive 1 rather than 2. I would like to ask for your help.

```
section .text
global _start

_start:

    FINIT
    FLD dword [zmA] ; zmA - st0
    FLD dword [zmB] ; zmB - st0, zmA - st1
    FLD dword [zmB] ; zmC - st0, zmB - st1, zmC - st2
    FLDZ ; 0 - st0, zmC - st1, zmB - st2, zmC - st3
    FADD st0,st2 ; zmB,zmC,zmB,zmA
    FMUL st0,st2 ; ZmB^2, zmC, zmB, zmA

    mov eax,4
    mov [delta],eax
    FILD dword [delta] ; 4, zmB^2, zmC, zmB, zmA

    FMUL st0,st4 ; 4zmA,zmB^2,zmC,zmB,zmA
    FMUL st0,st2 ; 4zmAzmC,zmB^2,zmC,zmB,zmA
    FSUBP st1,st0 ; zmB^2-4zmAzmC,zmC,zmB,zmA
    FSQRT ; making element of delta
    FIST dword [delta]

    xor ebx,ebx
    mov ebx,[delta]
    add ebx,48
    mov [delta],ebx

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,delta
    mov edx,4
    int 80h

    FLDZ ; 0, sqrt. delta, zmC, zmB, zmA
    FSUB st0,st3 ; -zmB, sqrt. delta, zmC, zmB, zmA
    FSUB st0,st1 ; -zmB - sqrt. delta, zmC, zmB, zmA
    FXCH st4 ; zmA, sqrt. delta, zmC, zmB, -zmB- sqrt. delta
    FLD dword [zmA] ; zmA, sqrt. delta, zmC, zmB, -zmB - sqrt. delta
    FADDP st1,st0 ; 2zmA, sqrt. delta, zmC, zmB, -zmB - sqrt. delta
    FXCH st4 ; -zmB - sqrt. delta, sqrt. delta, zmC, zmB, 2zmA
    FISTP dword [result]

    xor ebx,ebx
    mov ebx,[result]
    add ebx,48
    mov [result],ebx

    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,result
    mov edx,4
    int 80h

    mov eax,1
    int 80h

section .data
zmA     dd      1.0
zmB     dd      -7.0
zmC     dd      10.0
delta   dd      0
result  dd      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a typo here:

```
FLD dword [zmB] ; zmC - st0, zmB - st1, zmC - st2
```

That instruction should be `FLD dword [zmC]`

---

By the way, you can replace these two lines:

```
FLDZ ; 0 - st0, zmC - st1, zmB - st2, zmC - st3
FADD st0,st2 ; zmB,zmC,zmB,zmA
```

with:

```
FLD st1
```

Comment: What a simple mistake. Thank you man. I suspect I wouldn't find it out.